# Is it safe to have sources from different distributions in `sources.list`?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running Debian testing (`bookworm` by the time of this writing), and I need a package available only in the older Debian 10 (`buster`; today it is coded as "[oldstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable)").

I managed to add the relevant `buster` line to `sources.list`, update, and install the package. But later I was worried that this might introduce some inconsistency into the system and deleted that line.

Is it safe to have two `main` components from two different distributions? It is most likely that the distance between distro versions will diverge, as the package was not included in Debian 11. What is the advisable way to do this?

Comment: No, it's not safe and even installing a deb package manually is not safe. It can lead to dependencies problems later on. I'd recommend 1. compiling from sources and installing in e.g. /opt/package or 2. creating a snap/flatpak package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It is not safe](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), in the sense that it might work today and not work after an update. Since it is using new libraries, something could fail in a way that would be pretty hard to trace. So, in a word, no, it's not *safe*.

A better way to go about it is to pull the source and [rebuild the package](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html) with the development tools in your current Debian. It might take some time (some development libraries might not be longer available and you will have to also get them from source).

Anyway, do check the package page in Debian, to find out more on why it is no longer shipped. That might also help solve other issues when rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe as long as the two distributions won't conflict on the same package. And no, it is not possible to predict if there will be such conflict or not.

It is usually safe to add application-specific sources into your source list. For example, I constantly keep in my list a Microsoft's repo, since I use VS Code. I am relatively certain it will not conflict with Ubuntu's repo, which is primary on my machine.

But for cases like you are describing - with an application from another version of the same distribution - it would be easier and safer to download the single application package and install it locally. It most likely would require some other libraries, but will take them from the main (your real main "main" distro), so there would be no conflicts.

The only disadvantage of downloading a specific package: it will not be updated automatically. If developers publish a new version, you would have to take care of the updating manually yourself. In that case, it would be a controlled download and you would see which additional packages the new version of the app requires, so chance of conflict is minimized.

If you are taking the app from an old version of a distribution, it is possible it would require an old library which is not in the modern distributions. In that case, knowing which package is required, you can just repeat the process: download that additional package, install it locally, be sure there is no conflicts in dependencies. Try to install the app again. Repeat if necessary.